# Setting Property for Form2 in Form1 produces Nothing

Tags: vb.net

I upgraded a VB6 project to .NET and things are not working as expected.

I used to be able to load public properties from one class into another but those properties are null when checked.

```
Form1:
Dim frm1 As New Form1
frm1.empId = Me.empId.Text
Form2.Show()

Form2:
Public empId As Integer

Form_Load in Form2:
MsgBox(empId) // Null
```

I am expecting Form2 to echo the employee ID but it's null, or empty.

What am I doing wrong?

---

---

**EDIT**

This is the exact code I'm using.

```
This is FrmSerialize
Private Sub CmdLogin_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdLogin.Click
    FrmAutoCheck.empId = Me.empId.Text
    FrmAutoCheck.orderNo = Me.orderNo.Text
    FrmAutoCheck.partNo = Me.partNo.Text
    FrmAutoCheck.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

This is FrmAutoCheck: This is where I want to echo my property
Private Sub FrmAutoCheck_Load(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'The empId is a public property, set at the top of the FrmAutoCheck class
    'So, I am expecting to see the value of empId, since Form1.CmdLogin set this value
    MsgBox(empId)
End Sub
```

Comment: This code sets the property _empId_ in an instance of Form1. Why do you expect to be set in the default instance of Form2?

Comment: `I upgraded a VB6 project to .NET and things are not working as expected.`  It's been like that for almost 20 years.  At what point are you setting Form2 empID?

Comment: Are you sure that ` Me.empId.Text` is not empty? And are u sure that `empId` is not changed anywhere else. It would be worth defining a new property in `FrmAutoCheck` and assigning a literal to it in `Frm1` and showing it in `FrmAutoCheck_Load` to see how that reacts.

Comment: @CodePope, 100% positive. I can echo the value in my first form but that value never makes it over to the second

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the property `empId` of `Form1`, but loading `Form2`. Try that:

```
Form1:
Dim frm2 As New Form2
frm2.empId = Me.empId.Text
frm2.Show()
```

When you upgrade from VB6 to .Net, it does not create an object for the form when calling the `Show()` method, but calls the `FormX.Show()`. You have to change it as shown in the code by instantiating the class and setting the property.

Comment: @NaN Could you share exactly your code. The part you are calling the form and the form.load, because what you have shared is wrong.